# How to create unique key that also matches null or empty fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create some kind of "unique constraint" that counts `null` fields as a match.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id int,
    firstname varchar,
    lastname varchar,
    dob date,
    primary key (id)
);
```

I want to prevent creating duplicates that who match *either* the exact values *or* an empty field.

Example:

```
INSERT (john, doe, 2000-01-01);
INSERT (john, null, null); //should not be possible, there is already a 'john'
INSERT (null, doe, null); //should not be possible, there is already a 'doe'
INSERT (jane, doe, null); //should be possible, as there is no jane doe yet.
```

On persist, I want to check if there is already an entry that matches:

```
WHERE (firstname='john' or firstname is null) and (lastname = 'doe' or lastname is null) and (dob = '2000-01-01' or dob is null)...
```

And if there is a match: prevent the insertion.
I know this is not a real unique key, but I'm probably missing the correct term here?

Question: is there some kind of **generic** solution for this type of problem?

Comment: I suppose even MySQL wants `firstname IS null`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a trigger, something like that

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[person_Dup_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[person]
AFTER INSERT  
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.person S
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON
            -- Test for a duplicate
            S.firstname = I.firstname
            OR S.lastname = I.lastname
            -- But ensure the duplicate is a *different* record - assumes a unique ID
            AND S.ID <> I.ID
    )
    BEGIN
        THROW 51000, 'should not be possible, there is already a record', 1; 
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that condition you want to check

```
WHERE (firstname='john' or firstname is null) and (lastname = 'doe' or lastname is null) and (dob = '2000-01-01' or dob is null)...
```

forbids any null insertion, for example it would be impossible to insert

```
INSERT (john, null, null);
```

at all, even if it is the first insert in person table. Is this what you want to achieve?
If you only what to prevent multiple null values I'd try this:

```
create unique index idx1 on person(coalesce(firstname, 'null'), coalesce(lastname, 'null'), coalesce(dob, 'null'));
```

Edit: Above solution works only with assumption that we do not expect literal value `'null'` to represent firstName neither lastName or dob :) because it will not be allowed to insert.

On the other hand if you want only not-null values to be unique (every `null` is unique for MySQL DB) then index

```
create unique index idx1 on person(firstname, lastname, dob);
```

should do the job.

Comment: The `coalesce()` is indeed a nice trick to overcome the `null` problem in mysql. Good idea!